# Script fail to expand asterisk (`*`)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script to collect nmon data every hour:

```
#!/bin/bash
# olympics_yymmdd_HHMM.nmon
time_stamp=`date +"%y%m%d"`
h_name="$HOSTNAME"
exec > /var/log/nmon_capture.log
n_name=$h_name"_"$time_stamp"_*.nmon"
n_dir="/var/log/nmon_data"
cd $n_dir
sleep 1m
pwd
ls -al $n_name
#
/usr/bin/nmon -f -t -s 60 -c 1440 -m $n_dir
gzip $n_name
ls -al
exit
```

Debug output shows an issue with listing file. However, this works fine in other servers.

```
# bash -x /usr/bin/nmon_capture 
++ date +%y%m%d 
+ time_stamp=170217 
+ h_name=olympics 
+ exec 
+ n_name='olympics_170217_*.nmon' 
+ n_dir=/var/log/nmon_data 
+ cd /var/log/nmon_data 
+ sleep 1m 
+ pwd 
+ ls -al 'olympics_170217_*.nmon' 
ls: cannot access olympics_170217_*.nmon: No such file or directory 
+ /usr/bin/nmon -f -t -s 60 -c 1440 -m /var/log/nmon_data 
+ gzip olympics_170217_1504.nmon 
+ ls -al 
+ exit
```

Comment: Where did the single quotes around `olympics_*.nmon` come from?

Comment: @thrig That is what i am trying to find out, in other servers single quotes doesn't come up when i do ls -al $n_name

Comment: @thrig The single quotes are the usual way in which a `-x` presents its output. Nothing wrong there.

Comment: What this means is that the $n_name file does not exist on this "olympics" server. The single quotes come out when the glob does not expand to a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an assignment, the right side is considered quoted:

```
n_name=$h_name"_"$time_stamp"_*.nmon"
```

Therefore, the asterisk (`*`) will be included verbatim in the variable.
It will not be expanded as it is usual with asterisks in paths.

As it is probable that you do not have a file with an asterisk in the directory, the file is not found and an error is emitted by `ls`.

---

Also, if you do want the expansion of asterisks to work, it should be done in the directory where the file should be found:

```
a_dir=/dir_to_file
n_name=$(echo "${a_dir}/${h_name}_${time_stamp}_"*".nmon")    
n_dir="/var/log/nmon_data"
cd "$n_dir"
```

And, it is a very good idea to use the shell option `nullglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

to avoid that the `*` is retained if there is no file with that name.

Or, even better, to use the option `failglob`:

```
shopt -s failglob
```

To have a clear error emitted when no file is found.

```
a_dir=/dir_to_file
n_name=$(shopt -s failglob; echo "$a_dir/${h_name}_${time_stamp}_"*".nmon")
(( $? )) && exit 1
```

Adjust the value of "$n_dir" to your needs (it isn't clear from your description of the problem).

And please: quote your expansions by default, like: `ls -al "$n_name"`